# Как получить ответ на POST в виде byte[]?

Tags: c#

```
string postData = "post string";
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://122.233.155.155:80");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentLength = postData.Length;
req.Timeout = 10000;
using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream()) stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
{
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Так получаю ответ в виде string, а как получить в виде массива байтов byte[] ?

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` устарел, используйте `HttpClient` вместо него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не используйте `StreamReader`, так как он предназначен для чтения текста.
Взамен можно использовать промежуточный `MemoryStream`.

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

---

Кроме того, используйте асинхронный код:

```
using (Stream stream = await req.GetRequestStreamAsync())
    await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await req.GetResponseAsync())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: В чем преимущество GetResponseAsync и GetRequestStreamAsync ?

Comment: @Mart - Преимущество в асинхронности. Пока выполняются IO-операции (запросы идут по сети туда и обратно), поток (thread) не занимается и может быть отдан под выполнение других задач. В целом это повышает производительность при наличии большого количества запросов.

Comment: Почему вы даете пример для заведомо устаревшего API?

Comment: @aepot - Потому что вопрос именно про этот API.

Comment: Хорошо, но предупредить можно было.